# Error invoking class method via function pointer on a wrapped object

Tags: c++

I am coming from C background and new to CPP. I have a situation where I need to call a method on an object which will modify object. But on return from method, I need to restore object to its previous state. To achieve this I am using suffix, prefix wrapper technique illustrated by "Bjarne Stroustrup".

Along with this technique I am also trying to use function template and function pointer to generalize the methods that will be called on modified object.

```
template < class T >
class Call_proxy {
   T* obj;
   int ID;
public:
   Call_proxy( T* pp ) : obj( pp ), ID( i ) {      
   }

   ~Call_proxy() {
      obj->setID( ID );
   }

   T* operator ->() {
      return obj;
   }
};

template < class T >
class Proxy {
   T* obj;
   int ID;
public:
   Proxy(T* pp) : obj(pp), ID(pp->getID()) { }

   Call_proxy<T> operator ->() {
      return Call_proxy<T>( obj, ID );
   }
};

class X
{
   int id;
public:
   int getID();
   void setID(int ID) { id = ID; }
   void somefunction(int, int);
};

template<class X>
void doSomething(int nu, void(X::*fcn)(int, int))
{
   Proxy<X> P(x);
   P->setID(nu);
   (P->*fcn)(nu, 1); //This call generates error on VS2010: Error   1   error C2296: '->*' : illegal, left operand has type 'Proxy<T>'
}

int main()
{
   X x;
   doSomething<X>(1, &X::somefunction);
}
```

Can you please help me understand VS2010 keep complaining about `(P->*fcn)(nu, 1);` construct?

Comment: Might want to edit your post and include what it's complaining about along with the complete error message.

Comment: Regardless of the issue you're encountering, I suggest switching to a newer compiler.

Comment: Bah VS2010 is nothing to complain about. We had a guy on here earlier today trying to get some code working in Borland C++ 5.02.

Comment: There are assorted other bugs with this code. Please fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [expr.mptr.oper]:

> The binary operator `->*` binds its second operand, which shall be of type “pointer to member of `T`” to its
>   first operand, which shall be of type “pointer to `U`” where **`U` is either `T` or a class of which `T` is an unambiguous
>   and accessible base class**. The expression `E1->*E2` is converted into the equivalent form `(*(E1)).*E2`.

Even though `Proxy<T>` has `operator ->()` implemented, it doesn't matter, because:

```
(P->*fcn)(nu, 1);
```

would not use `operator ->`. It is special according to the grammar. You can *only* invoke `fcn` on a pointer to `X` (or something derived from `X`).

Comment: You can also overload `->*`, though with a member function pointer it's going to be somewhat complicated.

Comment: @T.C. I have never seen that before.

Comment: Thanks Barry. That citation was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

> void(X::*fcn)(int, int)

This is a pointer to a member function of the `X` class.

> (P->*fcn)(nu, 1)

This is attempting to use `P` to execute the member function **but** `P` is of type `Proxy<X>` (i.e., it's not of type `X` and it's not a pointer).